# Vuejs: 400 BAD REQUEST on patch ajax with vue-resoure and Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, patch, vue.js

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but my request URL for my Ajax Patch-request through Vue-resource is getting:

> 400 Bad Request

## But this is only on the local environment!!! When I push it up to the server, it works!

Does anyone know why?

Here is my request:

```
var id = thing.id;
            this.$http.patch('/api/things/' + id, thing).then(function(data){
                console.log('edited to: '+data);
});
```

The request parameters should all be correct when looking at the Network tab in dev tools.

Here is my Route:

```
Route::resource('/api/things','ThingsPanelController');
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Thing::findOrFail($id)->update([
        'body'=>$request->body,
    ]);
    return Response::json($request->all());
}
```

### Could it be because the ID I added was `'api/things' + id` and it sees it not as a wildcard in the route, but as a string! ?

This is my form I use. I prevent default and have the ajax request, so the form action shouldn't even be relevant...

```
<form action="update" @submit.prevent="doneEdit(thing)">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    <input type="text"
        v-model="thing.body"
        v-thing-focus="thing == editedThing"
        @blur="doneEdit(thing)"
        @keyup.esc="cancelEdit(thing)"
    >
</form>
```

Comment: 1. Not very familiar with laravel, so not sure if this is in the right direction at all, but: Do you maybe need to specify the type of request (`patch` in this case) in the route? 2. *Could it be because this method is inside a vue-component, instead of a vue-instance?* I'm certain that this is not the case.

Comment: 1) I've seen people do it without this. I'm not sure what's bugging in my case... : (

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was not relevent, I see what you mean. try looking here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-resource-patch-put-not-sending-the-data

Comment: @DevinGray If I check my ajax request in the network tab, I see the request was properly made with all data. I've read the thread you sent me, but I don't see any similar problems, as my data gets sent properly in the request, but it just outputs a 400 bad request...

Comment: Can you add the form into the question?

Comment: Cool having a look now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117418/discussion-between-devin-gray-and-mesqueeb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the problem is persistent on your **local server** AS WELL AS your **live server**.

In this case the problem was only on the local server. Then just do this:
Stop artisan's serve, and execute: `php artisan cache:clear`

Then try again: `php artisan serve` and the problem should be solved.

The problem might be caused because of a program like **CodeKit**. Even though your `php artisan serve` would serve on ip 8000, CodeKit changes this for auto reload reasons. This messes up the ajax call uri's.